# installing python packages via pip issues

Tags: pip, python-3.4

all I want is install pandas comfortably the package pandas via pip. 
Inside python I get the following error message:

```
>>> pip install pandas
c:\python34\python.exe: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Allright then I use the windows powershell

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Python34\python.exe -m pip install pandas
C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I had uninstalled and reinstalled python because I used at first the 32-Bit version but wanted 64-Bit, but had some issues so switched back to the 32-Bit version.

Before the reinstallation process I remember, that I could get pip to work but due to proxy issues didn't get very far. I am not a hundred percent positive but I might have gotten around the proxy issue at least.

Don't know what to do. Can somebody help. 
thanks
Gerrit

Comment: It should be `C:\Python34\python.exe -m pip install pandas`